# How can I create a mysql select subquery this on laravel 5 query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this query below with a subquery.
How do I generate it in laravel 5 query builder?
The thing that is bothering me is the sub query that shares the column from the first query.

```
    SELECT
    DATE(review_headers.`created_at`) AS `date`,
    COUNT(review_headers.id) AS reviews,
    (
          SELECT 
        (ROUND((SUM(IF(rd2.`param_value` >=9, 1,0))/COUNT(rh2.id))*100,2)) - (ROUND((SUM(IF(rd2.`param_value` <7, 1,0))/COUNT(rh2.id))*100,2))
          FROM review_headers rh2
          INNER JOIN review_details rd2 ON rd2.review_header_id = rh2.id
          WHERE DATE(rh2.created_at) <= DATE(review_headers.`created_at`)
       ) AS cumulativeNPS
FROM review_headers
INNER JOIN review_details ON review_details.review_header_id = review_headers.id
GROUP BY DATE(review_headers.`created_at`)
ORDER BY DATE(review_headers.`created_at`)
```

The tables:

review_headers

```
id  subject                           created_at  
------  -----------------------  ---------------------
20  review 8                   2016-03-31 15:50:57
21  review 9                   2016-03-30 15:50:57
22  review 10                  2016-01-14 15:50:57
23  review 16                  2016-04-25 08:19:03
24  review 17                  2016-04-25 08:19:03
25  review 18                  2016-04-19 08:19:03
26  review 19                  2016-04-18 08:19:03
27  review 20                  2016-04-17 08:19:03
28  review 21                  2016-04-07 08:19:03
29  review 22                  2016-03-27 08:19:03
30  review 23                  2016-03-25 08:19:03
31  review 24                  2016-04-25 08:19:03
32  review 25                  2016-04-25 08:19:03
33  review 26                  2016-04-19 08:19:03
34  review 27                  2016-04-18 08:19:03
35  review 28                  2016-04-17 08:19:03
36  review 29                  2016-03-27 08:19:03
37  review 30                  2016-03-25 08:19:03
```

review_details

```
id  review_header_id  param_value  
------  ----------------  -------------
97                21  7            
103                22  4            
109                23  8            
115                24  5            
121                25  6            
127                26  8            
133                27  9            
139                28  9            
145                29  5            
151                30  9            
157                31  3            
163                32  8            
169                33  10           
175                34  4            
181                35  7            
187                36  4            
193                37  7
```

Comment: What do you already have?

Comment: You want to use `DB::raw()` where you need to go beyond what the query builder provides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here You have complete code based on your query:

```
$subQuery = \DB::table('review_headers as rh2')
    ->select(\DB::raw('ROUND((SUM(IF(rd2.`param_value` >=9, 1,0))/COUNT(rh2.id))*100,2)) - (ROUND((SUM(IF(rd2.`param_value` <7, 1,0))/COUNT(rh2.id))*100,2)'))
    ->join('review_details as rd2'. 'rd2.review_header_id', '=', 'rh2.id')
    ->whereRaw('DATE(rh2.created_at) <= DATE(review_headers.`created_at`)');
$query = \DB::table('review_headers')
     ->select(
         \DB::raw('DATE(review_headers.created_at) AS date'),
         \DB::raw('COUNT(review_headers.id) AS reviews'),
         \DB::raw('(' . $subQuery->toSql() . ') as cumulativeNPS')
     )
     ->join('review_details', 'review_details.review_header_id', '=', 'review_headers.id')
     ->groupBy('review_headers.created_at')
     ->orderByRaw('DATE(review_headers.created_at)')
     ->mergeBindings($subQuery);
```

Comment: Is there any speed advantage of  doing this rather than putting the subquery directly in the DB:raw?

Comment: Ther is no speed advantage, but You will have objected subQuery and You can safely bind it. I also add: `->mergeBindings($subQuery);` which will copy bindings from subquery to the main query. In your example you don't have any - but it's a good practice to do it like this (also if You change some day SQL engine).

Comment: Cool, make sense. Cheers.

Comment: Didn't know about `mergeBindings` awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it seems to work.

```
$data = ReviewHeader::select(
    DB::raw('DATE(review_headers.`created_at`) AS dateTime'),
    DB::raw('(SELECT 
                (ROUND((SUM(IF(rd2.`param_value` >=9, 1,0))/COUNT(rh2.id))*100,2)) - (ROUND((SUM(IF(rd2.`param_value` <7, 1,0))/COUNT(rh2.id))*100,2))
                  FROM review_headers rh2
                  INNER JOIN review_details rd2 ON rd2.review_header_id = rh2.id
                  WHERE DATE(rh2.created_at) <= DATE(review_headers.`created_at`)
               ) AS cumulativeNPS'),
    DB::raw('COUNT(review_headers.id) AS review')
)
->join('review_details', 'review_details.review_header_id', '=', 'review_headers.id')
->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(review_headers.`created_at`)'))
->orderBy('review_headers.created_at')
```